# Docker - alias DNS entry (CNAME) for services

Tags: docker, networking, dns, docker-swarm, dnsmasq

Problem setup:

- Docker Swarm
- 3 services are running: `service-something` and `service-another` and `service-database`
- `service-something` and `service-another` use `service-database` to store data, like `mongodb://service-database/blahblah`

*What I want:*

Instead of `mongodb://service-database/blahblah` I want to use `mongodb://my-special-host/blahblah`

Ideally I want some sort of a CNAME where `my-special-host` resolves to `service-database`. That way I can update this entry once to `service-new-database`, and all my consumer services will be consuming the new database.

I know I can do this using `dnsmasq` on plain linux, but I am confused how to use this in a container base ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use docker network [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) options

in your stack `.yml` file :

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
  service-database:
    image: postgres:9.5.16-alpine
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - my-special-host
```

if you want to use same host name from your host machine, add this to your `/etc/hosts` file :

```
127.0.0.1 my-special-host
```

**Note:** make sure to expose ports to use db from outside